# Mysql Cluster vs Percona/Maridb Cluster

Tags: mysql, clustering, percona

We want to setup a mysql cluster with master-master sync replication, to provide HA so that one db for write from one app, other for write from other app. It is a webapp with high write and medium read

We are considering adding mysql cluster and considering percona vs mysql cluster.

Can MySQL ndb cluster import innodb dump ?

Can ndb cluster support MySQL async and 2-way sync replication ?

Can ndb guarantee consistency since it does not write to disk? I.e. What if there is 2 node cluster and both go down and data is not flushed to disk

can ndb cluster support 4-5 table join, ? Will the tables be in same node or will there be any network latency due to distributed joins

Does ndb cluster support MySQL-fabric Python api ?

Does ndb cluster support multi-master bi-directional sync?

Does percona cluster support above items ?

Comment: AIUI, MySQL Cluster is an In-Memory based system, whereas Percona/MariaDB systems are disk based.

Comment: Not anymore.  Or, at least the NDB Cluster data can be on disk now.

Comment: Why question is still on hold?

Comment: 3 people have voted to reopen. 2 more votes are needed.

Comment: We had exact same issues in production every day. We spend months trying to figure out correct answers.                                                              All these moderators are a bunch of babies, give nerds a little bit of power and it goes str8 to their heads. 'opinion based' my a..

Comment: Old thread but heres my two cents. we are using MySQL-Cluster-gpl- version 7.4.12  from last 4 months which involves 2 managemt, 2 data and 2 sql nodes. The engine used is called "ndbcluster" & although we can import/create innodb tables those are not replicated across the data nodes so its no use. Regarding performance we have avg. of (selects:200 update:150 insert:60 delete:20) QPS. and its performance is good so far(php/mysql app response time) + lot of query and table optimization(indexing stuffs) is a must here . I would also like to hear about your decision and performance too cheers :)

Comment: ndb cluster supports "master-master" and master-slave too. It also supports consistency since data is flushed every few seconds .check out LCP and GCP here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-basics.html  . yes mysql cluster supports multi-master and databases are mirrored hence they exist on both datanodes. We have used joins for up to 3 tables but i think you should use as few tables joins as possible. I dont know about percona and python api

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which is "better" -- Percona's PXC or MariaDB w/Galera.  Both use Galera as the underlying "cluster" technology and HA.  Percona is based on Oracle's 5.6, MariaDB is slightly forked back around 5.5 timeframe.  But both are great.

In any case, you really need 3 servers to get HA.  The 3rd is the tie-breaker in case one goes down.

Furthermore, if HA is a big priority, the think about tornadoes, earthquakes, floods, etc.  The 3 machines should not be in the same geographic location.

Bottom line:  Flip a coin for picking between them.  (I'm eager to hear from those who have a strong bias, but if you do, please state whether you have ties to one or the other.)

Don't use NDB Cluster -- it is too far from the main path of things.  There is a lot of setup required, and it has a bunch of limitations.

Comment: Thanks, But It appears that mysql-cluster in ndb storage engine and we are usign innodb. also it keeps some data in-memory with periodic flush to disk. ? is this a good choice for our innodb app? Also it seems it can handle only simple queries. That is why we are leaning toward Percona/Mariadb